# Transmission gives Permission denied Error

Tags: server, permissions, bittorrent, transmission

I updated my home ubuntu server with a lot of updates (I think it was quite 1 year I didn't update anything).

After this Transmission setting file `/var/lib/transmission-daemon/info/settings.json` disappeared. I wrote it again, Transmission starts but after a while it stops with this error:

> errr Unable to save resume file Permission denied

I gave permission 755 at the following folder and sub:

- `/var/lib/transmission-daemon/info`
- `/var/lib/transmission-daemon/download`
- `/media/virtual/downloads` ("download-dir")

---

This is what I get with strace:

```
sandro@naSan:~$ strace -f -e open transmission-daemon
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/usr/lib/libminiupnpc.so.8", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libevent-2.0.so.5", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl-gnutls.so.4", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libidn.so.11", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librtmp.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.11", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.26", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi_krb5.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblber-2.4.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap_r-2.4.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtasn1.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.3", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libk5crypto.so.3", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcom_err.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5support.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsasl2.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi.so.3", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkeyutils.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libheimntlm.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.26", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasn1.so.8", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhcrypto.so.4", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libroken.so.18", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwind.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libheimbase.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhx509.so.5", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
Process 3138 attached
[pid  3138] open("/dev/null", O_RDWR)   = 3
[pid  3137] +++ exited with 0 +++
Process 3139 attached
Process 3140 attached
[pid  3140] open(0x7efd059823c0, O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or dire                        ctory)
[pid  3140] open(0x7efd059823f8, O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 13
[pid  3140] open(0x7efd059823cd, O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 13
[pid  3140] open(0x7efd059823cd, O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 13
[pid  3140] open(0x7efcf8000f00, O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 13
[pid  3140] open(0x7efd059843cc, O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 13
[pid  3140] open(0x7efd0547b435, O_RDONLY|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK) = 15
[pid  3140] open(0x4611f8, O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 15
[pid  3140] open(0x4611f8, O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 15
[pid  3140] open(0x4611f8, O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 15
[pid  3140] open(0x4611f8, O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 15
[pid  3140] open(0x4611f8, O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 15
Process 3141 attached
[pid  3138] open(0x1a15420, O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_EXCL, 0600) = 19
[pid  3138] open(0x7efd04c91ab0, O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 20
[pid  3141] open(0x7efcf00008c0, O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or dire                        ctory)
[pid  3140] open(0x46485e, O_RDONLY)    = 20
[pid  3138] open(0x7efd04c911f0, O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 21
[pid  3141] open(0x7efd04c92a91, O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 20
[pid  3141] open(0x7efd04c92bcd, O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 20
[pid  3141] open(0x7efd05fc0e47, O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 20
[pid  3141] open(0x7efd061bfe62, O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 20
[pid  3141] open(0x7efd04c92ad8, O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 20
[pid  3141] open(0x7efcfee06fc1, O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 20
[pid  3141] open(0x7efd05fc0e47, O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 20
[pid  3141] open(0x7efd061bff0c, O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 20
[pid  3141] open(0x7efd04c92a91, O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 20
[pid  3141] open(0x7efd04c91625, O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 20
[pid  3141] open(0x7efcfee06fc1, O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 20
[pid  3141] open(0x7efcfee06fc1, O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 20
[pid  3141] open(0x7efcfee06fc1, O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 20
[pid  3141] open(0x7efcfee06fc1, O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 20
[pid  3141] open(0x7efcfee06fc1, O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 20
[pid  3141] +++ exited with 0 +++
```

Now I get this error from the web interface:

```
403: Forbidden

Unauthorized IP Address.

Either disable the IP address whitelist or add your address to it.

If you're editing settings.json, see the 'rpc-whitelist' and 'rpc-whitelist-enabled' entries.

If you're still using ACLs, use a whitelist instead. See the transmission-daemon manpage for details.
```

File "settings.json" and "stats.json" have lost 775 and are now 600.

Comment: you could try running it via strace and filter the output to just open calls to see which files its opening or failing to open. strace -f -e open transmission if you don't have strace installed you can install it by doing apt-get install strace

Comment: I solved the problem: see my answer below

Comment: How are you running Transmission? As a system daemon or as a user daemon?

Comment: Sorry, David. I don't know

Comment: How do you start Transmission? Do you start it from a (possibly graphical) user session or with the system service manager (`service`, `initctl`, systemd depending on the init system of your Ubuntu release)? Or is it started automatically on system start or user log-in?

Comment: ok, Transmission is a service that starts on boot

Answer (score 1):

I solved this way:

1) Uninstall Transmission. All of it. Every package.

```
sudo apt-get autoremove transmission-common
```

2) Delete every transmission* package in /var/cache/apt/archives

```
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/transmission*
```

3) Check if your package manager is working properly

```
sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get update
```

4) Install Transmission again

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:transmissionbt/ppa

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install transmission-cli transmission-common transmission-daemon
```